# AngulaJS $watch variable with a weird name

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For reasons that don't bare going into here, I have a variable named `placements[]` on $scope. As in `$scope.object['placements[]'] = { .. }`. I would like to watch this variable, but it doesn't seem that there exists a way to watch a variable like this, since `$watch` takes an expression.

There isn't anything about how to handle this on the angular docs, so if anyone has a tip or trick that would be great. My current workaround is to `$scope.$watch('object', function() {} , true)`, but that is far from a perfect solution.

Comment: Does `$scope.$watch("object['placements[]']", function() {})` work?

Answer (score 1):

I am a dunce. Obviously since angular expressions *are valid javascript expressions*, you can do this:

```
$scope.$watch("object['placements[]']", callback, true);
```

Ugly as hell but it works

Answer (score -1):

`$scope.$watch` can take function or a string. In this case it makes sense to pass a function returning the object to watch

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope['placements[]']; }, function(value) { ... });
```

This is assuming your scope object looks like:

```
{
    'placements[]': {...}
}
```

Comment: I edited your post to work properly, but it should be noted that `$scope.$watch('something[]')` does not work